# How to set itext pdf table alernative rows colour in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am generating pdf file from database using itext pdf library.Now my need i that i have to show alternative rows of pdf table in different colour just like zebra colour (grey and white)
but i dont know how to do that...

Here is my code..

```
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);
        table.setTotalWidth(100);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        while (rs.next()) {
            table.addCell(rs.getString("date"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("time"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("source"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("destination"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("extension"));
         }
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
boolean b = true;
for(PdfPRow r: table.getRows()) {
  for(PdfPCell c: r.getCells()) {
    c.setBackgroundColor(b ? BaseColor.GREY : BaseColor.WHITE);
  }
  b = !b;
}
```

Comment: sir i need alternating rows but here it is coming in alternating columns

Comment: I got error in `PdfPRow r: table.getRows()` , say Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to PdfPRow

Comment: @parlad neupane should work. What versions of itext and Java are you using?

Comment: using `com.github.librepdf` (openPdf) maven dependency v1.2.18, I get the same error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to Object`. Workaround for this was this...

`for (Iterator i = pdfPTable.getRows().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

      PdfPRow r = (PdfPRow) i.next();
      ...
}`

But getting NPE on this line `c.setBackgroundColor(b ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);`

Console logging `pdfPTable.size()` outputs 15. So I know rows exist.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following with `iText 7`

```
Table table = ...
int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = ...
Cell cell = null;
boolean condition = true;

for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++) {

    cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Column 1"));
    cell.setBackgroundColor(condition ? Color.GREY: Color.WHITE);
    table.addCell(cell);

    cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Column 2"));
    cell.setBackgroundColor(condition ? Color.GREY : Color.WHITE);
    table.addCell(cell);

    cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Column 3"));
    cell.setBackgroundColor(condition ? Color.GREY : Color.WHITE);
    table.addCell(cell);

    condition = !condition;
}
```